# How depends Xcode "Change Editor Orientation" menu option to the location of the assistant editor?

Tags: xcode, xcode12

Xcode 12 is annoying me. In the storyboard I want to display the assistant editor below the storyboard but Xcodes sometimes stucks the editor to the right side.
Changing the menu option "Change Editor Orientation" seems to reflect the whole editor position but not the position of the assistant editor itself.
Even the orientation is set to vertical, sometimes the assistant editor goes to the right side, sometimes below.
So as I mentioned above that's what I want, I want to force Xcode to show the assistant always on the bottom side. But it always stucks onn the vertical, right position.
Even if a new editor with horizontal oriantation is opened, the position of the assitant editor won't change.

[image]

Also the layout pane is always greyed out and stuck in automatic despite I don't use the focused editor:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change its orientation By shortcut key
Press `Option` Key and hover on the editor icon.
[image]

This will give the below output.

[image]

Comment: This is not the assistant editor, that's a complete new editor window. If you would click above into a view controller above, the editor you opened below is not synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, for all desperates Xcode beginners: The Layout Panel becomes active if the assistant editor is opened regardeless the orientation:

[image]

Choosing the right or bottom changes the position of the assistant editor immediality.